# Eclipse RCP help broken after update of 4.12

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, help-system

I have updated an eclipse rich client platform product from version 4.4.2 to 4.12. All is working fine expect the help. I get an 500 error. Its the help which uses an internal jetty-server.

Strangely the context-help and help-search is working fine. I found out the help is working fine till Eclipse rcp 4.7.3. After version 4.7.3 is it broken for all other versions.

I´m not sure what is the problem. How can I find the cause of this? I added the stack trace of the help.

````
HTTP ERROR 500 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: 
PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP 
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp 
PWC6199: Generated servlet error: SearchData cannot be resolved to a type 
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp 
PWC6199: Generated servlet error: SearchData cannot be resolved to a type 

URI:
/help/advanced/tocView.jsp 

STATUS:
500 

MESSAGE:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: SearchData cannot be resolved to a type PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: SearchData cannot be resolved to a type  

SERVLET:
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet-246bbda0 

CAUSED BY:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: SearchData cannot be resolved to a type PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: SearchData cannot be resolved to a type  

Caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
SearchData cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /advanced/tocView.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
SearchData cannot be resolved to a type


    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl$LegacyServlet.service(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.dispatch(ProxyServlet.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.preprocess(ProxyServlet.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)```
````

Comment: A plug-in might be missing in your RCP application. Which `org.apache.lucene.*` plug-ins do you have? Which version of `org.eclipse.help.base` and `org.eclipse.help.webapp`?

Comment: Assuming you are using a '.product' file for the RCP build try the 'Add Required' button on the 'Content' tab to make sure you have all plug-ins/features.

Comment: @howlger
I have the following org.apache.lucence.* plug-ins:
org.apache.lucene.analyzers-common
org.apache.lucene.analyzers-smartcn
org.apache.lucene.core

Comment: @greg-449
I already tried the 'Add Required'.

Comment: @howlger
my org.eclipse.help.base is version 4.2.800.v20191210-0610 
my org.eclipse.help.webapp is version 3.9.700.v20191123-0656